# java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes, But jar isn't signed

Tags: java, maven, manifest, signed

if i try to build my jar, and execute it, i am getting this error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:330)
at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:263)
at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:318)
at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:230)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.ensureInitialization(JarFile.java:612)
at java.util.jar.JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.ensureInitialization(JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.java:69)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:991)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
```

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main"

The jar isn't signed or anything else.

Link to project: https://github.com/IndexOutOfMJ/TNE-DiscordBot

Comment: What kind of Java application is this? Because that error indicates your JAR is not signed (exactly like you say), **but** it **must** be signed to run.

Comment: This is a discord bot with an implementation of google spreadsheet

Comment: It also worked for a while.

Comment: And you have posted a partial stack trace and no code. Best of luck!

Comment: I signed the jar, but the same error occures.

Comment: I uploaded it to github:
https://github.com/IndexOutOfMJ/TNE-DiscordBot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

```
zip -d yourjar.jar 'META-INF/*.SF' 'META-INF/*.RSA' 'META-INF/*SF'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25723902)